# Prediction when Target's lag values are part of Predictors

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, python, forecasting, lightgbm

I'm using LGBM for regression, where the Target column's lagged values (*7 columns for each lag day*) are also used as predictors when training the model. Absence of the 7Day lag values severely increases MAE value.

Now when using the model in production, if I use the complete data as training dataset, how to get the 7day lag value of the time period I'm planning to predict? I obviously won't have the target value, to calculate it's 7Day lag value. What to do now?

**To explain in more detail**: 
So, I'm predicting sales amount (*Target variable y*). The model is trained on 20 predictors (*X*), and 7 of them are the lag value of the Target Variable, i.e. *Sales_Amount_Lag1, Sales_Amount_lag2, Sales_Amount_lag3 ...... Sales_Amount_lag7*.

The thing is, while preparing the model, I had access to both X & y dataset, thus I could easily calculate `y`'s Lag values. 
Now, when predicting for future timestamps (**Sales haven't occurred yet**), I won't be having `y`. So how do I calculate the lag values, which is required in the trained model's predictor columns now?

Comment: Do a one step forecast at a time and then feed the forecasted value back into the lagged predictor variables